Trying to reference the source code for journal to replicate
After searching the web for a solution and not finding a library, I'm instead trying to write a systemd journal reader using csharp and not having much luck.
There's an example written in c++ at the bottom of the following link:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/sd_journal_next.html
<<< SEE UPDATE BELOW >>>
This is the code I have so far, which, when I run it, I get
$ ./LogPublisher 
errno: 0
errno: -10
errno: -10
errno: -10 Message: 

As far as I can tell, -10 refers to No child processes as taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    enum Flags
    {
        SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY = 1 << 0,                 // 0000 0001 = 1
        SD_JOURNAL_RUNTIME_ONLY = 1 << 1,               // 0000 0010 = 2
        SD_JOURNAL_SYSTEM = 1 << 2,                     // 0000 0100 = 4
        SD_JOURNAL_CURRENT_USER = 1 << 3,               // 0000 1000 = 8
        SD_JOURNAL_OS_ROOT = 1 << 4,                    // 0001 0000 = 16
        SD_JOURNAL_ALL_NAMESPACES = 1 << 5,             // (32) Show all namespaces, not just the default or specified one */
        SD_JOURNAL_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = 1 << 6,  // (64) Show default namespace in addition to specified one */
        SD_JOURNAL_TAKE_DIRECTORY_FD = 1 << 7,          // (128) sd_journal_open_directory_fd() will take ownership of the provided file descriptor. */
        SD_JOURNAL_ASSUME_IMMUTABLE = 1 << 8,           // (256) Assume the opened journal files are immutable. Journal entries added later may be ignored. */
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct Journal
    {
        public int toplevel_fd;  // int toplevel_fd;
        public string path;  // char *path;
        public string prefix;  // char *prefix;
        public string _namespace;  // char *namespace;
        public UIntPtr files;  // OrderedHashmap *files;
        public UIntPtr files_cache;  // IteratedCache *files_cache;
        public UIntPtr mmap;  // MMapCache *mmap;
        public UIntPtr newest_by_boot_id;  // NewestByBootId *newest_by_boot_id;
        public ulong n_newest_by_boot_id;  // size_t n_newest_by_boot_id;
        public UIntPtr current_location;  // Location current_location;
        public UIntPtr current_file;  // JournalFile *current_file;
        public ulong current_field;  // uint64_t current_field;
        public UIntPtr level0;  // Match *level0;
        public UIntPtr level1;  // Match *level1;
        public UIntPtr level2;  // Match *level2;
        public UIntPtr exclude_syslog_identifiers;  // Set *exclude_syslog_identifiers;
        public ulong origin_id;  // uint64_t origin_id;
        public int inotify_fd;  // int inotify_fd;
        public uint current_invalidate_counter;  // unsigned current_invalidate_counter
        public uint last_invalidate_counter;  // unsigned last_invalidate_counter
        public ulong last_process_usec;  // usec_t last_process_usec;
        public uint generation;  // unsigned generation;
        public string unique_field;  // char *unique_field;
        public UIntPtr unique_file;  // JournalFile *unique_file;
        public ulong unique_offset;  // uint64_t unique_offset;
        public UIntPtr fields_file;  // JournalFile *fields_file;
        public ulong fields_offset;  // uint64_t fields_offset;
        public ulong fields_hash_table_index;  // uint64_t fields_hash_table_index;
        public string fields_buffer;  // char *fields_buffer;
        public int flags;  // int flags;
        public bool on_network = true;  // bool on_network:1;
        public bool no_new_files = true;  // bool no_new_files:1;
        public bool no_inotify = true;  // bool no_inotify:1;
        public bool unique_file_lost = true;  // bool unique_file_lost:1;
        public bool fields_file_lost = true;  // bool fields_file_lost:1;
        public bool has_runtime_files = true;  // bool has_runtime_files:1;
        public bool has_persistent_files = true;  // bool has_persistent_files:1;
        public ulong data_threshold;  // size_t data_threshold;
        public UIntPtr directories_by_path;  // Hashmap *directories_by_path;
        public UIntPtr directories_by_wd;  // Hashmap *directories_by_wd;
        public UIntPtr errors;  // Hashmap *errors;

        public Journal() { }
    }

    internal static class Systemd
    {
        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_open(ref Journal sd_journal, int flags);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern void sd_journal_close(ref Journal sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_seek_head(ref Journal sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_seek_tail(ref Journal sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_next(ref Journal sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_previous(ref Journal sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_get_data(ref Journal sd_journal, string field, [Out] StringBuilder data, [Out] ulong length);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int errno;
        Journal j = new();

        errno = Systemd.sd_journal_open(ref j, (int)Flags.SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY);
        Console.WriteLine($"errno: {errno}");

        Console.WriteLine($"path: {j.path}");

        errno = Systemd.sd_journal_seek_head(ref j);
        Console.WriteLine($"errno: {errno}");

        errno = Systemd.sd_journal_next(ref j);
        Console.WriteLine($"errno: {errno}");

        ulong length = 0;
        StringBuilder data = new(1024 * 768 * 4);

        errno = Systemd.sd_journal_get_data(ref j, "MESSAGE", data, length);
        Console.WriteLine($"errno: {errno} Message: {data}");

        Systemd.sd_journal_close(ref j);
    }
}

I've been trying to reference the source code for journal to replicate but just cant work it out.
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/systemd/sd-journal.h
With reference to the code above, why am I getting that error?  Am I on the right track with the code or am I way off? Have I referenced the Journal correctly with using ref Journal j? Has anyone written something similar and can share their code?
UPDATE
With thanks from those in the comments, progress has been made.  The output now gives me
$ ./LogPublisher 
result: 0
result: 0
result: 1
result: -22 Message: 0 Length: 0

With the following code
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    enum Flags
    {
        SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY = 1 << 0,                 // 0000 0001 = 1
        SD_JOURNAL_RUNTIME_ONLY = 1 << 1,               // 0000 0010 = 2
        SD_JOURNAL_SYSTEM = 1 << 2,                     // 0000 0100 = 4
        SD_JOURNAL_CURRENT_USER = 1 << 3,               // 0000 1000 = 8
        SD_JOURNAL_OS_ROOT = 1 << 4,                    // 0001 0000 = 16
        SD_JOURNAL_ALL_NAMESPACES = 1 << 5,             // (32) Show all namespaces, not just the default or specified one */
        SD_JOURNAL_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = 1 << 6,  // (64) Show default namespace in addition to specified one */
        SD_JOURNAL_TAKE_DIRECTORY_FD = 1 << 7,          // (128) sd_journal_open_directory_fd() will take ownership of the provided file descriptor. */
        SD_JOURNAL_ASSUME_IMMUTABLE = 1 << 8,           // (256) Assume the opened journal files are immutable. Journal entries added later may be ignored. */
    }

    static class Systemd
    {
        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_open(ref UIntPtr sd_journal, int flags);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern void sd_journal_close(UIntPtr sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_seek_head(UIntPtr sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_seek_tail(UIntPtr sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_step_one(UIntPtr sd_journal, int advanced);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_next(UIntPtr sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_previous(UIntPtr sd_journal);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_get_data(UIntPtr sd_journal, string field, UIntPtr data, out ulong length);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int result; // negative number on error
        UIntPtr j = new();

        result = Systemd.sd_journal_open(ref j, (int)Flags.SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY);
        Console.WriteLine($"result: {result}");  // return 0 on success

        result = Systemd.sd_journal_seek_head(j);
        Console.WriteLine($"result: {result}");  // return 0 on success

        result = Systemd.sd_journal_step_one(j, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"result: {result}");  // return the number of entries advanced/set back on success

        UIntPtr data = new();

        result = Systemd.sd_journal_get_data(j, "MESSAGE", data, out ulong length);
        Console.WriteLine($"result: {result} Message: {data} Length: {length}");

        Systemd.sd_journal_close(j);
    }
}

Not quite there yet as I dont get a result from get_data...

Recommendation: Print out the failing error code, then exit the program. Continuing after you know it failed is not a good idea. Eventually it fools you into thinking things worked when in reality they stopped working a while ago.

At no point did you ask a question ...

@user4581301 sometimes advancing to the next error gives more clarity on the first error.

@ChrisMM harsh but true. Was a late night question after hours of trying to work it out. Have added questions, please reopen.

Where do you come up with that definition of struct Journal? It looks very different from what struct sd_journal looks like so I don't expect that you will get this to work.

@TedLyngmo I was hoping to use a cut back version because the struct has structs within structs within structs.... guessing i cant get away with that :)

@Christian Perhaps you can, if its possible to define a pointer a struct without definition in c# and then supply a pointer to such a pointer to the sd-functions. Never try to read/write any members inside though.

Most of the member structures are pointers so if you don't need them then you can just use UnitPtr instead

@AlanBirtles I've updated the question with the new code... still getting -10 errno :/

current_location isn't a pointer

Actually, looking at the functions, I dont need access to the sd_journal struct. I just need to pass it into each function so can i just use internal static extern int sd_journal_open(UIntPtr sd_journal, int flags);

You probably don't need struct Journal at all, you can just use it as an opaque pointer. Note that sd_journal_open takes a pointer to a pointer, not a pointer like the other methods

@AlanBirtles ok, i got it! internal static extern int sd_journal_open(ref UIntPtr sd_journal, int flags); and then UIntPtr j = new(); errno = Systemd.sd_journal_open(ref j, (int)Flags.SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY);

if you've solved your problem you should post the details as an answer

Not solved yet. Still cant get the data out... Im setting data to InPtr and using string? message = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(data); and getting result: 0 Message:  Length: 256

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    enum Flags
    {
        SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY = 1 << 0,                 // 0000 0001 = 1
        SD_JOURNAL_RUNTIME_ONLY = 1 << 1,               // 0000 0010 = 2
        SD_JOURNAL_SYSTEM = 1 << 2,                     // 0000 0100 = 4
        SD_JOURNAL_CURRENT_USER = 1 << 3,               // 0000 1000 = 8
        SD_JOURNAL_OS_ROOT = 1 << 4,                    // 0001 0000 = 16
        SD_JOURNAL_ALL_NAMESPACES = 1 << 5,             // (32) Show all namespaces, not just the default or specified one */
        SD_JOURNAL_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = 1 << 6,  // (64) Show default namespace in addition to specified one */
        SD_JOURNAL_TAKE_DIRECTORY_FD = 1 << 7,          // (128) sd_journal_open_directory_fd() will take ownership of the provided file descriptor. */
        SD_JOURNAL_ASSUME_IMMUTABLE = 1 << 8,           // (256) Assume the opened journal files are immutable. Journal entries added later may be ignored. */
    }

    static class Systemd
    {
        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_open(ref UIntPtr sd_journal, int flags);
        // int sd_journal_open(sd_journal **ret, int flags);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern void sd_journal_close(UIntPtr sd_journal);
        // void sd_journal_close(sd_journal *j);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_seek_head(UIntPtr sd_journal);
        // int sd_journal_seek_head(sd_journal *j);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_seek_tail(UIntPtr sd_journal);
        // int sd_journal_seek_tail(sd_journal *j);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_step_one(UIntPtr sd_journal, int advanced);
        // int sd_journal_step_one(sd_journal *j, int advanced);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_next(UIntPtr sd_journal);
        // int sd_journal_next(sd_journal *j);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_previous(UIntPtr sd_journal);
        // int sd_journal_previous(sd_journal *j);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_get_data(UIntPtr sd_journal, string field, ref IntPtr data, ref ulong length);
        // int sd_journal_get_data(sd_journal *j, const char *field, const void **data, size_t *l);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_get_realtime_usec(UIntPtr sd_journal, ref ulong usec);
        // int sd_journal_get_realtime_usec(sd_journal *j, uint64_t *usec);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int sd_journal_enumerate_data(UIntPtr sd_journal, ref IntPtr data, ref ulong length);
        // int sd_journal_enumerate_data(sd_journal* j, const void** data, size_t *length);

        [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern void sd_journal_restart_data(UIntPtr sd_journal);
        // void sd_journal_restart_data(sd_journal *j);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        UIntPtr j = new();
        int result; // negative number on error

        result = Systemd.sd_journal_open(ref j, 0);
        if (result != 0) throw new Exception($"Error {result} opening journal");

        result = Systemd.sd_journal_seek_head(j);
        if (result != 0) throw new Exception($"Error {result} seeking to head");

        ulong _ulong;
        IntPtr _intPtr;

        while (true)
        {
            List<object?> kv = [];

            result = Systemd.sd_journal_step_one(j, 1);  // return the number of entries advanced/set back on success
            if (result < 1) break; // end of stream

            _ulong = 0;
            result = Systemd.sd_journal_get_realtime_usec(j, ref _ulong);
            if (result != 0) throw new Exception("Error getting __REALTIME_TIMESTAMP");
            kv.Add($"__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP={_ulong}");

            do
            {
                _intPtr = new(); _ulong = 0;

                result = Systemd.sd_journal_enumerate_data(j, ref _intPtr, ref _ulong);
                if (result < 0) throw new Exception($"Error {result} getting data");
                if (result > 0) kv.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(_intPtr));
            } while (result > 0);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("&", kv));
        }

        Systemd.sd_journal_close(j);
    }
}


Please explain how this code actually solves the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

@DarkBee code only answers are "ok" answers. better than nothing. difficult to explain all the parts that made it work. anyone can see and go through it i feel.
